# Extract maximum numeric value from given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, max, python-re

Given an alphanumeric string `S`, extract maximum numeric value from that string. All the alphabets are in lower case. Take the maximum consecutive digits as a single number.

Example Input: `23dsa43dsa98`
Expected Output: `98`

I tried:

```
import re
a=input()
item=([re.split(r'(\d+)', s) for s in (a)])
print(item)
```

Answer (score 4):

This would work:

```
max(re.findall('\d+', a), key = lambda x: int(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
res = re.findall(r'\d+', a)
max(list(map(int, res)))
```